# Cannot modify list

Tags: c#

I am making a simple ATM and I faced a problem.

Application: http://pastebin.com/Uk1q5vpC
Handle command: http://pastebin.com/eG8XWM4w

Account:

```
class Konto
{
    public Bankkort bankkort;
    private string namn;
    public string losenord;
    public int pengar;
    public Kontoutdrag ku = new Kontoutdrag();

    public Konto(Bankkort bk, string n, string l, int p)
    {
        bankkort = bk;
        namn = n;
        losenord = l;
        pengar = p;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return namn;
    }
}
```

Withdraw:

```
class Uttagning : Kommando
{
    public void Hantera(Konto konto)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Du har " + konto.pengar + " kr. Hur mycket vill du ta ut?");

        string inmatning = Console.ReadLine();
        konto.pengar -= int.Parse(inmatning);
        konto.ku.log.Add("Uttagning: " + inmatning);

        Console.WriteLine("Nu har du " + konto.pengar + " kr!");
    }
}
```

Statements (a log that shows when and how much you deposit or withdraw):

```
class Kontoutdrag : Kommando
{
    public List<string> log = new List<string>();

    public void Hantera(Konto konto)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < log.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(log[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I will try my best to explain my issue. I withdraw 500 dollars and want to save it to a log (List). Every account has a "Statement"/Log if you check `public Kontoutdrag ku = new Kontoutdrag();` in the `Account` class. I modify the Log list `konto.ku.log.Add("Uttagning: " + inmatning);` in `Hantera` method in the the `Withdraw` class. But when calling the `Hantera` method in "Statement"/Log it doesn't print out anything.

Steps:

```
--> Call the `Hantera` method in the `Withdraw` class  
--> Change the List in the "Statement"/Log class  
--> Call the `Hantera` method in "Statement"/Log class  
--> Doesn't print out anything
```

Please tell me if you misunderstood me and sorry for the naming (It's in Swedish). You're welcome to change this text and the title.

Comment: Shouldn't `Kontoutdrag.Hantera` do *something* with the `Konto` you pass in?

Comment: We need to see the code in "Main"

Comment: @RowlandShaw Yes, this is unfinished.

Comment: @Maor Vietsman http://pastebin.com/hz5MRRW0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    case "c":
        kom = new Kontoutdrag();
        break;
// …

new HanteraKommando().Hantera(kom, list[i]);
```

As you can see, you are creating a new `Kontoutdrag` object which you then pass to the Hantera command. Of course, that new  `Kontoutdrag` also comes with its own (empty) list, so when you call the method on that, it doesn’t print anything.

Instead, you should get the existing object from the `Konto` object. Something like this:

```
Konto konto = list[i];

Kommando kom = null;
string kommando = Console.ReadLine();
switch (kommando)
{
    // …
    case "c":
        // get the existing object
        kom = konto.ku;
        break;
}

new HanteraKommando().Hantera(kom, konto);
```